# PyQt: How to get the item at a specific position in a TreeWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt

How do I get the item at a specific position (the first, the last, or any given position) of a TreeWidget? I am interested only on items at the parent level, so that I can programmatically select an item at that position.

I searched for more than an hour without finding any clear example.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually looked in [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreewidget.html#itemAt) ?, you can probably look in to itemAt or itemFromIndex

Comment: As a matter of fact, I looked at the docs first! itemAt and itemFromIndex do not seem to be what I need because these methods require the 'coordinates of a viewport'. It is a pity that the documentation for Qt/PyQt is so poorly provided with examples.

Comment: Well, it turns out that itemAt() has indeed solved my problem! The 'viewport coordinates' can be simply the row, col of the desired item. But again, it is regrettable that the docs are so cryptic and devoid of good examples.